# E: Unable to locate package usb_modeswitch

Tags: 12.04, installation, usb

I am using Ubuntu 12.04 and have been trying to get it to detect my Micromax data card. I have been trying to install usb_modeswitch, but I keep getting the follow error -

E: Unable to locate package usb_modeswitch

I also tried editing the etc/apt/sources.list and added the following :

```
deb http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted universe
deb-src http://archive.ubuntu.com/ubuntu/ maverick main restricted universe
```

Still no improvement. What am I not doing right?

Any help will be appreciated. Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 2):

The package is called `usb-modeswitch` (with `-` instead of `_`).

The lines you have added are for *Ubuntu 10.10 "Maverick Meerkat"*. They do not work on *Ubuntu 12.04 "Precise Pangolin"*

Comment: I tried usb-modeswitch. it gives the following error:
     E: Could not get lock /var/lib/apt/lists/lock - open (11: Resource temporarily unavailable)
     E: Unable to lock directory /var/lib/apt/lists/

There is no other installation/updation running. Plus, it is executing in root mode.

Comment: Have a look at [Fixing “Could not get lock /var/lib/dpkg/lock”](http://askubuntu.com/questions/15433/fixing-could-not-get-lock-var-lib-dpkg-lock)